# Aggregating child features with parent attribute values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, layers, atlas, aggregation

I found this question when looking for my answer [Referring to the parent layer with aggregate functions in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300045/referring-to-the-parent-layer-with-aggregate-functions-in-qgis)

I need to do something similar. In another words I need to *join attributes by field value* using the expressions in Field Calculator. I want values of a given layer to sum up based on the value of an attribute in an atlas. Here is my code:

```
aggregate(
    layer:=*child layer*,
    aggregate:='sum',
    expression:=*child layer attribute to be summed*,
    filter:=*Child layer attribute to check*=attribute(@parent,*parent attribute to check*)
    )
```

I am using the expression `attribute()`, but I don't know if this exists, it's just something I have seen in the linked topic, but it doesn't work.

There is probably a work-around using an aggregate within aggregate, but this seems too complicated.

To explain a little more. I have polygons (child layer) with values inside several areas (parent layer, also polygons). Previously I added the parent area codes to the child polygons polygons in the past based on location. Now I am getting incorrect sums based on aggregate filtered by location, I need to validate the calculations and I cannot figure out another way to check, so I need to sum it up by filed values (the ones I added also based on location). I probably should be looking on different ways to check my calculations, but this is the step I am at and need help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly where the error is, perhaps syntax (when mixing up `aggregate()` and `attribute()` you need to be careful about when to use single vs double quotes to refer to layers), or where you've used the expression.

If I understand correctly, you have a parent layer attribute (e.g. ABC, XYZ), and you want to sum the child layer numeric values (e.g. 5, 10, 15) *as a column in the parent layer*, where parent layer attribute = child layer attribute (i.e. parent ABC = child ABC).

The example below shows how you would achieve that. Is this what you are after?

---

Existing `parent_layer` (with attribute `parent_attribute`) and `child_layer` (with attributes `child_attribute` and `child_value_to_sum`)

[image]

In the **parent layer**, open field calculator, create new field called `summed_child_values` and use the following expression - note when to use the single and double quotes

```
aggregate('child_layer',
          'sum',
          "child_value_to_sum",
          "child_attribute"=attribute(@parent,'parent_attribute'))
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

---

Replace above layer names and column names as appropriate

Comment: how can i transform the aggregate expression to have the same expression but with current_feature (@parent). When i create child in child layer have the attribute 'sum_child_value' in parent layer that updates over time ?